# Can't set background color in footer

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hey guys I am trying to set a background color in a div tag, however nothing is happening. I feel like it is I have a floating element in my div, however I do not of have any way to solve it.

HTML

```
<div id='footer'>
      <h5>©Krish International Inc.
      </h5>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
   #footer {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
      }
 h5 {
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'hind';
@font-face {
    font-family: 'hind';
    src: url('C:/Users/lakes/Desktop/hind2.ttf')
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**about `position:absolute` :**

> When set to absolute or
>   fixed, the element is removed completely from the normal flow of the
>   document.

**cause:**

> `h2` have position `absolute` so removed completely from the normal flow of the document and `#footer` get `height:0`

**Fix:**

> You must define `height` or `min-height` for `#footer`.

```
 #footer {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        height: 100px;<------------Added
       //Or min-height:100px;
}
```

```css
 #footer {
        background-color: deepskyblue;;
        height: 100px;
  }

 h5 {
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'hind';
  }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'hind';
    src: url('C:/Users/lakes/Desktop/hind2.ttf')
  }
```

```html
  <div id="footer">
      <h5>©Krish International Inc.
      </h5>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using `position:absolute;` when you simply get it by following approach.

If you need to use `position` that parent div did't get height by default until you not give. because when we use the `position: absolute` div or tag come out of the flow.

```css
  #footer {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 100%;
}

h5 {
  font-weight: normal;
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'hind';
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'hind';
    src: url('C:/Users/lakes/Desktop/hind2.ttf')
  }
```

```html
<div id='footer'>
  <h5>©Krish International Inc.
  </h5>
</div>
```